# grunt compress to include hidden subfolders

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-compass

I'm trying to bundle a number of python dependencies from `/dist` into the main zip file to deploy it to lambda. These dependencies have hidden subfolders with required files (for whatever reason).

For instance:

`dist/psycopg2/.libs` or `dist/numpy/.libs`

Grunt skips those hidden subfolders with just this in `compress.dist.files`

```
{
  cwd: 'dist/',
  src: ['**', '**/.*'],
  dest: '/',
  expand: true
}
```

A hidden folder in `dist/.somefolder` is included that way but nothing in those subfolders. How can I get grunt to compress those as well

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this works:

```
{
cwd: 'dist/',
src: ['**'],
dest: '/',
dot: true,
expand: true
}
```